# HTTP CONNECT & stream_socket_client

Tags: php, stream-socket-client

what way would be best to send a HTTP CONNECT request via php's stream_socket_client?
or would it be irrelivant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to delegate the request to a proxy of some sort. The proxy should then handle the request/response between the two communicating entities.